# User: Bob does not have permission='CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE' for queue bob.test/test/signal/abc on address test/signal/abc

Tags: mqtt, paho, activemq-artemis

I have configured ActiveMQ Artemis `broker.xml` file in a way so that one user (Alice) will create the address/queue in Artemis with MQTT protocol.  Alice's role is configured such that it can create addresses/queues/send/consume

And the other user (Bob) will only consume/send messages in that queue.  Bob's role is configured such that it can only send and consume from topics.

But, I am getting below exceptions while doing the following:

1. Publishing to a topic using Alice
2. Subscribing to the same topic using Bob

Also getting the same exception when doing the following:

1. Subscribing to a topic using Alice
2. Subscribing to the same topic using Bob

```
Error processing Control Packet, Disconnecting Client: ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ229213: User: bob123 does not have permission='CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE' for queue bob.test/test/signal/abc on address test/signal/abc]
```

**broker.xml**:

```xml
<security-settings>
   <security-setting match="test/signal/#">
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user" type="createDurableQueue"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user" type="createAddress"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user" type="deleteAddress"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user,bob-user" type="send"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user,bob-user" type="consume"/>
      <permission roles="amq,alice-user,bob-user" type="browse"/>
      <permission type="manage" roles="amq,alice-user,bob-user"/>
   </security-setting>
</security-settings>

<address-settings>
   <address-setting match="test/signal/#">
      <default-exclusive-queue>true</default-exclusive-queue>
      <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
      <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
      <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      <slow-consumer-threshold>1</slow-consumer-threshold>
      <slow-consumer-policy>KILL</slow-consumer-policy>
      <slow-consumer-check-period>5</slow-consumer-check-period>
      <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
      <default-max-consumers>1</default-max-consumers>
      <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
      <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
      <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
      <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
      <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
   </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a subscription on the destination the user must have permission to create a queue. The queue *is* the subscription on the broker. You haven't given `bob123` this permission so the broker won't allow it.

Also, since you're using the MQTT syntax for destinations (which uses the `/` character) then you need to configure the broker to use this as the delimiter character so your matches will actually work for your `security-setting` and `address-setting`, e.g.:

```xml
<wildcard-addresses>
   <delimiter>/</delimiter>
</wildcard-addresses>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. wild card was already there. I have queue creation rights to Bob which solves the problem. Thank you for your prompt response. Now, I see the difference between address creation and queue creation. So, in my case user Alice has only rights to create address but in order to subscribe to that address user bob should be able to create/delete queue.